# Merge sort comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

How do we merge 4  sorted files containing 50, 10, 25 and 15 records ? Because selecting the order of merging  will reduce/increase the number of comparisons made.

Comment: You could try all 12 combinations: 6 ways to do the first merge, 2 ways to do a second merge for each of the 6 possible first merges, 1 way to do a third merge after the first and second merges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single merge, the number of comparisons depends on the record values, anywhere from 1 to the sum of the lengths of both files.

I would advise to merge the 10 and 15 record files first, then merge the resulting file with the 25 record file and finally merge the resulting 50 record file with the first 50 record file.

You could also implement a 4 way merge and merge all 4 files in parallel.

Keep in mind that the file lengths are very small, so the number of comparisons is not going to matter much for the final performance.

Comment: The total number of compares is small for all cases, but the difference is significant. Worst case number of compares for merging {{{10,15},25},50} = 172. Worst case for {{{50,10},15},25} = 232.